# Executing a Python Executable ZIP file using execfile()

Tags: python, zip

We can execute a single Python file inside another Python file using `execfile()`, but it only works on `.py` files.

In Python we can create an executable ZIP file (that contains `__main__.py` and other files)

How can I execute a ZIP file using `execfile()`?

Comment: extract the .py file in a temp location and run it, just like winzip/7zip/whatever does.

Comment: Actually, your solution works. Thanks, but I need something more clear.

Comment: what do you mean "more clear" ? can you [edt] to make your question clearer then?